# How to turn off notifications for a specific event in the calendar?

Tags: calendar, notifications, ical

I have a recurring event in my work calendar that occurs every day.  I would like to continue to get notifications for the rest of my events, but disable the notifications for only this recurring one.

I [found instructions](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21854?locale=en_US) on how to disable notifications on the calendar for a number of different situations but not this specific one.  Is there any way to turn off notifications for a single recurring event?

Answer (score 2):

There are two places where you will need to disable this.

1. As @howdytom explained, set **alert** to *None* when editing your event. Calendar will ask you to save this change for all future events.

[image: Event Alerts]

2. Calendar creates automatic alerts for your events. To change those, go to **Calendar** → **Preferences** → **Alerts** and disable automatic alerts by setting them to *None*. Once you do this, this will affect automatic alerts for ALL events, and you will need to set them on an event-by-event basis.

[image: Automatic Alerts]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Simply disable the notification checkbox on your recurring appointment that you wish to overwrite. Once you hit save it will ask you to apply the changes to all upcoming or only one occurrence.